# Requesting Azure AD permissions on-demand

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We have a multi-tenant single page app (and backend) that uses Azure AD for authenticating users. We'd like do queries to customer's Azure AD for retrieving groups but make it an opt-in behavior for customers (tenants). The reasoning behind that is that not all customers necessary need the functionality and would rather not grant us access to their AAD unnecessarily.

Is there some way of implementing this with Azure AD?

I've been trying to test with different OAuth /authorize calls with resource IDs and scopes but mostly I end up with "*AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ''. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.*" error. Configuring the web app or backend to require the permission would surely fix the error but that will also make the approval of it mandatory for all users of the app.

Is there a way of using the authorize/consent API to request access to a new application on-demand?

An ugly work-around that should work would be to have 2 client IDs and 2 backend IDs with different permissions but ADAL.js doesn't seem to be designed to work with multiple Client IDs (it's singleton, for starters). Also Application Permissions should of course work but I'm not sure how much of those are required to search for groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of using the authorize/consent API to request access to
>   a new application on-demand?

Do take a look at [`Azure AD v2.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview). With their [`incremental & dynamic consent model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#incremental-and-dynamic-consent), it is possible to do so though I am not sure if this specific functionality (managing groups) is available there.

I had a discussion with Azure AD team member recently about this (as we are also facing the same problem) and he suggested that we take a look at this.

Essentially the way things work in Azure AD v2.0 is that you start with basic set of permissions (like sign in, read profile etc.). Then when some tenant need specific permission, you essentially ask them to grant those permissions to your application at that time only. What this means is that different users in your application have granted different permissions to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I had been reading some documentation regarding v2.0 but hadn't really realized the significance of it. It should indeed enable what we're after though I'm not sure if "incremental/dynamic _admin_ consent" is supported (needed as reading groups requires admin consent).

Comment: Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#admin-restricted-scopes. It talks about admin restricted scopes and how you can implement them. HTH.

Comment: Thanks. However, looking at [authentication libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries) it seems that v2.0 is a no-go for us as they don't really have official library for Single Page Apps (think ADAL.js) yet. Hello.js seems like an option but even that would be a rewrite of our authentication code.
I think we'll go for the Application Permissions and client id & secret route for now.

Comment: Agree with you on client libraries. MSAL (which has support for v2.0) has been in preview for ages. We're implementing protocol directly (not have any choice really right now) and using a mix of v1.0 & 2.0 in our application.

Comment: To add to the confusion [v2.0 Protocols - SPAs using the implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit) does mention/suggest using adal.js. Yet ADAL.js is using the old endpoints (see [code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L1021)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSAL, and looking for a way to dynamically change your scopes before authenticating, have a look at this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/configuration.md#msalguard---dynamic-auth-request

More here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/configuration.md#platformbrowserdynamic